# How to compute bias mean square error and standard error in penalized logistic regression?

Tags: r

I am working on my PhD research on penalized logistic regression.

In my simulation using R, I run the following code:

```
library(penalized)

x0 <- matrix(rnorm(100,1))
y <- as.numeric(runif(100)>0.5)
x <- as.matrix(cbind("Intercept"=1, x0))
n <- nrow(x)
p <- ncol(x)

penL1 <- penalized(y, x,lambda1=1,lambda2=0, positive = FALSE, fusedl=FALSE,
         model = "logistic", steps =1, epsilon = 1e-10, standardize = FALSE, trace = TRUE)
penL1
```

and it displays only the coefficients, but I also want to compute bias mean square error and standard error of the estimates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

From the `penalized` vignette:

> It is a very natural question to ask for standard errors of regression
>   coefficients or other estimated quantities. In principle such standard
>   errors can easily be calculated, e.g. using the bootstrap. Still, this
>   package deliberately does not provide them.
>
> The reason for this is that standard errors are not very meaningful
>   for strongly biased estimates such as arise from penalized estimation
>   methods. Penalized estimation is a procedure that reduces the variance
>   of estimators by introducing substantial bias. The bias of each
>   estimator is therefore a major component of its mean squared error,
>   whereas its variance may contribute only a small part.